# Extending jQuery vertical tab content area to the full page-width

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I've setup a vertical set of tabs as outlined [here](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical). However the content area only extends about halfway across the page.

[image: Content panel doesn't extend across the full width]

I've been trying to adjust the CSS to allow it to flow to the far edge of the page by adding `width='100%'` attributes to various UI CSS-tags or playing the built in width attribute values and it does extend the window but it starts putting the actual content in the wrong place.

For example if you remove the `width: 55em` from `.ui-tabs-vertical` the white container area does extend fully but the 'hello' text appears in the following spot:

[image: hello went on vacation to the middle right of the page]

How can I adjust the CSS to allow the content area to full the page width but still start at a nicely padded left side of the vertical tab list?

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhapgpxt/)

Comment: Add some code on jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Can not give an answer without going through the code..

Comment: @Vlad Done, sorry about that. I had it ready and forgot to add it to the post.

Comment: lol nobody is going throug 100k lines of code.. please adjust it with only the necessary css

Comment: @DomlThe-Bread It's standard jQueryUI css, the only interesting bits are the top 15 lines that are right out of the jquery documentation vertical sample link.

Comment: In addition to your asked problem you also have a problem where the tabs fail to work at all. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhapgpxt/1/). Assuming you have a working tab example you should post that fiddle instead.

Comment: @doveyg I noticed that but since it still demonstrated the layout issue with a single tab I didn't think it'd matter all that much.

Comment: for the most part I would agree, however there can be some cases where solutions can only partially fix the problem, its best we have as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel` rule from

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel 
{ 
  padding: 1em; 
  float: right; 
  width: 40em;
}
```

To float: left

```
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel 
{ 
  padding: 1em; 
  float: left; 
  width: 40em;
}
```

Appears to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If setting width might fix it, try doing this one :

```
width: calc(100% - 162px);
```

162px is what I assume the width of the left sidebar.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do much different then just reminding the `.ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }` style rule.

Comment: so setting a width isn't an option? Setting it to `width:100%` might not work on your case.

Comment: Swapping `.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}` from float right to float left actually seems to be doing what I want. Not exactly sure why though.